# Line missing from Latex table

Tags: latex

I have made a table in latex in the following format,

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{3.5cm}|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|p{1.0cm}|}
\hline
&\multicolumn{7}{c|}{Different values of K}\\
\cline{2-8}
1 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 &  8 & 9 & sum\\
\hline 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption {sum}
\label{tab:sum}
\end{table}
```

However when I run it, there is a line missing on the table at the top right corner. Can anyone please help me to fix this issue? I am not able to solve it.
I am using online latex.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a "&" at the end of this line:
`&\multicolumn{7}{c|}{Different values of K} &\\`

Comment: Thank you very much. That was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
 \begin{table}[h]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|p{3.5cm}|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|p{1.0cm}|}
 \hline
 &\multicolumn{7}{c|}{Different values of K}&\\
 \cline{2-8}
  1 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 &  8 & 9 & sum\\ \hline 
   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\\hline 
   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\\hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\\hline
 \end{tabular}
 \caption {sum}
 \label{tab:sum}
  \end{table}
  % Here is the corrected version. You need to replace H by h and 
 %after    sum put & sign
```